# Why cursor always goes to beginning of EditText when click Toggle button in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, passwords, android-togglebutton

First of all, I apologize for my bad English Grammar.

There is a `toggleButton` and `EditText` in my Simple Android Application. When I click the toggle button `editText` Box change into the password field and a normal text field.
That is working perfectly, but the problem is when I click the toggle button cursor always goes to the beginning of the Text.

Example: When Type **stack** it shows as ..... after clicking toggle button that words appear but cursor goes into the front of 's' it does not stay after 'k'

How can I correct this issue?

**This is `EditText` and toggle Button `xml` code**

```
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etCommand"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/command"
            android:password="true" />
<ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tglBtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="75"
            android:checked="true"
            android:onClick="changeField"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text="ToggleButton" />
```

**and I change its behavior using the following code**

```
if (passTog.isChecked()) 
    {
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT| InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
    } 
    else 
    {
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer by myself

```
if (passTog.isChecked()) 
    {
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT| InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
        input.setSelection(input.length());
    } 
    else 
    {
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        input.setSelection(input.length());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing the following

```
int selstart = input.getSelectionStart();
int selend = input.getSelectionEnd();
input.setInputType(passTog.isChecked() ? (InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD) : (InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT));
input.setSelection(selstart,selend);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here test using this code to put the cursor at the end of the `EditText`:

```
yourEditText.setSelection(yourEditText.getText().length());
```