# Xamarin Entry sets CursorPosition to zero on toggling IsPassword (Android)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have an Entry that I'm using as a password.  Alongside that I've added an ImageButton that I press and hold to briefly show the password.   As you can see the 'IsPassword' is bound to the 'IsPressed' property of the button.  The problem I have is that the cursor gets reset to the start of the entry when I press and release the button.  Focus is not changing on the Entry, at least I don't see a property change event relating to focus.  This is unhelpful when a user is typing a password and wants a quick peek to see what they've typed.  I'd like the cursor to keep its position.

I tried adding a PropertyChanged handler to cache the current position and restore it, sequence of events makes this difficult and feels hacky.  Is there a better work-around for this?

```
<Entry
    Text="{Binding Password}" Keyboard="Plain" 
    IsPassword="{Binding Source={x:Reference previewPasswordButton},
                 Path=IsPressed, Converter={StaticResource boolInvertConverter}}">
</Entry>
```

Comment: When IsPassword property changes, the cursor position will come to first. Seems it is designed by Android. You may see the thread: [Why cursor always goes to beginning of EditText when click Toggle button in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690041/why-cursor-always-goes-to-beginning-of-edittext-when-click-toggle-button-in-andr)    That's why I recommend not to use Bindings to change the IsPassword property and just monitor the Button pressed and released action.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this in Forms. When IsPassword changed the cursor come to the first position.

I share a workaround to use a [Custom Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry) with the following steps:

**Creating the Custom Entry Control**

```
public class MyCustomEntry : Entry
{
    public MyCustomEntry()
    {
    }
}
```

**Consuming the Custom Control**

*xaml file*

```
<local:MyCustomEntry x:Name="myentry" 
       Text="{Binding Password}" Keyboard="Plain"        
    />
<ImageButton x:Name="previewPasswordButton"
            Pressed="previewPasswordButton_Pressed"
            Released="previewPasswordButton_Released" />
```

*cs file*, I use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to send message to native class:

```
void previewPasswordButton_Released(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage,bool>(this, "button",false);
}

void previewPasswordButton_Pressed(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage,bool>(this, "button",true);
}
```

**Creating the Custom Renderer on Android Platform**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyCustomEntry), typeof(MyCustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace EntryIsPassword77045393.Droid
{
    public class MyCustomEntryRenderer: EntryRenderer
    {

        int cursor_position;
        public MyCustomEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, bool>(this, "button", (s, e) =>
            {
                if(e)
                {
                    cursor_position = Control.SelectionStart;
                    Control.TransformationMethod = null;        
                    Control.SetSelection(cursor_position);
                }
                else
                {
                    cursor_position = Control.SelectionStart;
                    Control.TransformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod.Instance;
                    Control.SetSelection(cursor_position);
                }
            });
        }


        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);           
        }         
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I solved it differently by creating a  ContentView with the Entry control inside it and caching the cursor position on property changes and restoring it in the meantime.

Comment: Glad you solved it! You could add an answer to share your solution, which may help others with similar question.